# Prediction on test data using the bottleneck features of a pre-trained network in Keras

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, deep-learning, keras

I have followed the blog [building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html).
In section : Using the bottleneck features of a pre-trained network, VGG16 weights have been incorporated using bottle neck features.
I have got the fitted model and accuracy of training and validation set.

Now, I want to predict the test data. My test data is in the test folder which contains 100 images of cats and dogs.
How can I get Predictions of test data from model ?

I have tried the following :

```
 test_data_dir = '/Dogs_Cats/data/test'
 datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1., featurewise_center=True) 
 datagen.mean=np.array([103.939, 116.779, 123.68],dtype=np.float32).reshape(3,1,1)
 generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        test_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=32,
        shuffle=False,
        classes = None)

test_data_features = model.predict_generator(generator, 25)
np.save(open('/Dogs_Cats/data/test_data_features.npy','wb'), test_data_features)
test_data =np.load(open('/Dogs_Cats/data/test_data_features.npy','rb'))
predictions = model.predict_classes(test_data, verbose=1)
```

But, getting errors.

Comment: Could you post your errors?

Comment: Thanks for quick response.. I am getting the following errors :   Exception: Error when checking : expected flatten_input_5 to have shape (None, 512, 4, 4) but got array with shape (25, 3, 150, 150)

Comment: In the generator, what are img_width and img_height?